# jquery second function call not working

Tags: jquery, function, variables

Hi I am a noob and just starting to use JQuery.
I have created a function - createGrid- and saved it as a var.  I call this function on $(document).ready and it works.  When I try to call this function again on .click, it does nothing.  I have another function triggered by the same .click and it works.

I know it is possible to call two functions on a single event, and Ive looked at lots of different examples and just cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Here is my code:

```
var createGrid = function() {
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        $(".container").prepend("<div class='myDiv'></div>");
    }
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    createGrid();
    $(".navbar").prepend('<button class="btn shake">Shake</button>')
    $(".navbar").prepend('<button class="btn size">Pen Size</button>')
    $(".myDiv").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
    })
    $(".shake").click(function() {
        $(".myDiv").fadeOut();
        $(".shake").click(createGrid);
    });
});
```

I have tried running  the last part like this as well, but that didnt work either.

```
    $(".shake").click(function()
    $(".myDiv").fadeOut();
    });
    $(".shake").click(function() {
    createGrid();
    });
```

And also like this

```
    $(".shake").click(function()
    $(".myDiv").fadeOut();
    createGrid();
```

What am I missing?

Also, I have included all of this inside the $(document).ready, but I feel like the .click events should not need to be included inside of this.  However, when I end the .ready prior, and do not include the .click events they fail to trigger at all.  Is it necessary to have all the event codes run inside the .ready or am I just doing it wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

*As you are creating elements dynamically.* You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

*Use*

```
$(".container").on('mouseenter', ".myDiv", function(){
    //Your code
});
$(".navbar").on('click', ".shake", function(){
    //Your code
});
```

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

Comment: Ah ha!  Thank you so much!  I can stop banging my head against a wall and read about .on now.